# Can't use Archive_Zip in php which I just installed

Tags: php, cpanel, php-ziparchive, php-7.2

I installed Archive_Zip module (v0.1.2) from cPanel > PHP PEAR Packages.

But I still get error in PHP:

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found
```

Using `use ZipArchive` or `new \ZipArchive` didn't help.

How can I enable ZipArchive class in PHP 7.2 having access only on the cPanel (no terminal or anything else) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255921/php-fatal-error-uncaught-error-class-ziparchive-not-found-in)

Comment: @l'L'l thanks. But I already tried that answer. Doesn't help me. Dont forget I have access only on the cPanel.